# PHP: extract data from string in external file, to have three separate arrays or multidimensional one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a script that allows me to:

1. create a products database by saving all arrays in db_products.php file, using this format:

   ```
   $products[] = "Bread|2.0|0.50";
   $products[] = "Milk|3.0|0.70";
   ...
   ```

Where "Bread" is the item name, "2.0" is his price and "0.5" is the production cost;

2. in show_me_products.php, I would like to extract and insert all data in a pure html table, that looks like:

   ```
           | BREAD |  MILK | ... |
   price   | 2.00$ | 3.00$ | ... |
   costs   | 0.50$ | 0.70$ | ... |
   gain    | 1.50$ | 2.30$ | ... |
   ```

**What I tried to do**

```
$handle = "db_products.php";

fopen($handle, "r"); // or also file_get_contents
$count = count($products);

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){

list($product, $price, $cost) = explode("|", $products[$i]);

$product_array = implode(", ", $product);
  $price_array = implode(", ", $price);
   $cost_array = implode(",", $cost);

}

<html code...>
<table>
<tr>
<th></th>

<? foreach($product_array as $id => $prod): ?>    
<td><? echo $prod; ?></td>   
<? endforeach; ?>

</tr>
<tr>
<th>price</th>

<? foreach($product_array as $how => $much): ?>    
<td><? echo $much; ?></td>   
<? endforeach; ?>

...
```

This code doesn't works, of course.
I know that there are conceptual errors and that I should make better syntax choices, but I think to being a step away from a solution, but I can't see it.

What did I forget?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your contribution, Ryo.
It was helpful to fix an error in my script (include - fopen).
In fact db_product.php it wasn't a text file, then it was superfluous to use "fopen" to open a php file.
Anyway, my intention is to keep PHP code separate from HTML code.That's why I spoke about "a pure HTML table".
The data must remain clean in their reference arrays, without append HTML code in the strings.

Working on my code today, I found a potential solution.

```
include("file.php");

        $count = count($products);

$product_array = array(); // initialize product_array
  $price_array = array(); // initialize price_array
   $cost_array = array(); // initialize cost_array
   $gain_array = array(); // initialize gain_array

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++):

list($product, $price, $cost) = explode("|", $products[$i]);

$product_array[$i] = $product; // fill product_array
  $price_array[$i] = $price; // fill price_array
   $cost_array[$i] = $cost; // fill cost_array
   $gain_array[$i] = $price - $cost; // calculate difference and create gain_array

endfor;
?>

<html code...>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>

<? foreach($product_array as $product_unit): ?>
<th><? echo $product_unit; ?></th>
<? endforeach; ?>

</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>gain</th>

<? foreach($gain_array as $gain_unit): ?>
<td><? echo $gain_unit; ?></td>
<? endforeach; ?>

</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>price</th>

<? foreach($price_array as $price_unit): ?>
<td><? echo $price_unit; ?></td>
<? endforeach; ?>

</tr>
<tr>
<th>costs</th>

<? foreach($cost_array as $cost_unit): ?>
<td><? echo $cost_unit; ?></td>
<? endforeach; ?>

</tr>
</table>
```

This code works perfectly, but isn't clean and stylish as I would like.
Is there a better way to do this, considering I want to keep separate php code and html code?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below to see if that is the result you expect, in your original code, you probably dont need fopen, just simply include the php file (it's simply echo the sctript), if it's like you description that `db_products.php` only has product array. secondly, you can join the string with html tags instead of using mutiple for loop. Below is my first attempt, please check if it is what you expect. I will do some modifications once I got more time. thanks

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

include('file.php'); #simply include the product array


$count = count($products);
$header = '<td></td><td>'; #Product headers first column is empty
$priceRow = '<td>price</td><td>'; #Price row, first column to store row name
$costRow = '<td>cost</td><td>'; #cost
$gainRow = '<td>gain</td><td>'; #gain
echo '<table>';

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){

    list($product, $price, $cost) = explode("|", $products[$i]);
    $header .= $product . '</td><td>';
    $priceRow .= $price . '</td><td>';
    $costRow .= $cost . '</td><td>';
    $gainRow .= $price-$cost . '</td><td>';

}

#print header
echo '<tr>';
echo $header;
echo '</tr>';

#print price
echo '<tr>';
echo $priceRow;
echo '</tr>';

#print cost
echo '<tr>';
echo $costRow;
echo '</tr>';

#print gain
echo '<tr>';
echo $gainRow;
echo '</tr>';

echo '</table>';
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you ryo, I answered you exhaustively in a separate contribution, because my answer might be helpful to other users :)